# Extending a provided class

Tags: c#

I have extended a class like so:

```
public class CormantRadDock : Telerik.Web.UI.RadDock
{
    public enum Charts { LineChart, PieChart, BarChart };

    public Charts ChartType { get; set; }
    public bool LegendEnabled { get; set; }
    public string ChartName { get; set; }

    public CormantRadDock() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

I am now trying to adjust some code elsewhere to accommodate this update.

The old code was this:

```
List<RadDock> docks = new List<RadDock>(dockLayout.RegisteredDocks);
```

where RegisteredDocks is of type `"System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<RadDock>"`

I do not understand why this is not possible:

```
List<CormantRadDock> docks = new List<CormantRadDock>(dockLayout.RegisteredDocks);
```

I receive the errors:

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.List(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments.

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

Could someone please explain why this is occurring and a best possible solution?

Comment: Your old and new code looks the same to me.  What does RegisteredDocks have to do with CormantRadDock?  Why did its type change?

Comment: I iterate over RegisteredDocks to record all the properties of each dock. I extended RadDock to give it more properties. I need to save these new properties, as well. As such, while iterating over the list, I can either explicitly cast each RadDock as a CormantRadDock to access its additional properties, or (what I'm trying to do) cast the entire list of RadDock as CormantRadDock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the `RegisteredDocks` might not be `CormantRadDock`, so they can't be added to a `List<CormantRadDock>`.

If you're only interested in the CormantRadDocks, you can filter by type:

```
List<CormantRadDock> docks = dockLayout.RegisteredDocks.OfType<CormantRadDock>().ToList();
```

If you know for sure that `RegisteredDocks` will only contain CormantRadDocks, you can cast each item:

```
List<CormantRadDock> docks = dockLayout.RegisteredDocks.Cast<CormantRadDock>().ToList();
```